# Conditional Tenses in English

Tags: conditionals

I was studying conditional tenses, and i have come up with 3 sentences which involve the same. Need some help in assessing them.

1. Ahh! It's sunday. If i was a good cook, i would invite my girlfriend for lunch.
2. I wouldn't have waited for her, if i had known, she would be that late.
3. If i had cooked this a bit long, it would look even more good.

Are the above sentences correct?

Comment: By "assessing them", do you mean checking them for grammatical correctness?

Comment: yes, .... why? do you feel "assessing them" doesn't fit here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All three sentences need a little loving care:

1. Ahh! It's Sunday. If **I were** a good cook, I would invite my girlfriend for lunch.
2. I wouldn't have waited for her if I had known she would be that late. (Remove both commas as impeding the flow.)
3. If I had cooked this a bit longer, it would look even better. (The conditional was fine, but the rest needed help in making sense.)